# Storing Keys with no Values in Redis

Tags: redis

I want a data structure to hold onto a list of naughty words.  Before I allow a user to continue I need to make sure none of their words are found on this naughty list.

So its a simple lookup to see if a key exists.  There is no value associated with each cuss word.

Can I use Redis this way?

Comment: If you want to use redis keys for the 'naughty words' then just set the value to `0` or `1` (`true` or `false`). That way you have control over which words are 'naughty' and 'when'.

Comment: Makes sense.  The words are always naughty, i'll just load them all up with a value of 1.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You can store them in a set `SADD naughty word1 word2 word3` and then you can query it by `SISMEMBER naughty word1` which results in `true` (actually `1` but that's the translation)

Comment: I'm curious about performance.  Is this equal or better than the suggestion of adding them as separate Keys with a value of 1?

Comment: As long as you insert those in a batch, it's faster than adding them one by one. Redis handles at least 10kOps/Sec in my setups.

Comment: Actually i meant what about the speed of the lookups.  I'll be loading them up in batch like you say, but i want the lookups to be as fast as possible.

Comment: Depends on how you will access them and your use-case. Either `SMEMBERS` to get them all, `SISMEMBER` for single access or, `SSCAN` using patterns to search. There is no one-fits-it-all answer. 1 access, is fast (only some ms) 1000 accesses are slower.

Answer (score 0):

I know its pretty late to reply to this question. But, came across a cleaner implementation in redis blog, which uses SADD, SISMEMBER and SINTER to solve similar problem. Here's the [link](https://redislabs.com/blog/use-redis-content-filtering/)